# How to convert any number into decimal value upto 2 decimal places?

Tags: postgresql

I have a values in a table which are numbers(decimal and integer).I need a query which can convert them to decimal.
I tried the following query:

```
select sellingprice,concat('$',to_char(sellingprice,'FM0999.90')) from cmp2.productdetails;
```

The result:

```
14.4    |   $0014.40
84      |   $0084.00
7.7     |   $0007.70
0.01    |   $0000.01
17.28   |   $0017.28
110     |   $0110.00
0.13    |   $0000.13
0.1     |   $0000.10
1       |   $0001.00
1000    |   $1000.00
```

It gave me all unnecessary leading zeroes.A single 0 before the decimal point is good if the value is for example 0.1 it should return $0.10 .
I want the query to return

```
14.4    |    $14.40
84      |    $84.00
7.7     |    $7.70
0.01    |    $0.01
17.28   |    $17.28
110     |    $110.00
0.13    |    $0.13
0.1     |    $0.10
1       |    $1.00
1000    |    $1000.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `FM9990.90`:

```
postgres=# select c, to_char(c,'$FM9990.90') from t;
   c    | to_char  
--------+----------
  14.40 | $14.40
   7.70 | $7.70
 110.70 | $110.70
  17.28 | $17.28
  84.00 | $84.00
    0.1 | $0.10
   0.01 | $0.01
   1000 | $1000.00
      1 | $1.00
(9 rows)
```

Comment: It doesn't give me the desired output

Comment: Try my updated answer. If this is not OK please give an example.

Comment: your updated answer gives 2 digits after the decimal point which is correct, but when the number is 0.1 or 0.01 it returns $.10 and $.01.The query should return $0.10 and $0.01